# How to apply Scale animation After Translate animation in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi am doing one app here  i need to  apply rotate,move scale animation to my imageview..i tried using below code rotate and scale animation working well but in scale animation image is not scaling in where translate animation stoped that postion its coming back to original postion there its scaling..but i need to scale image where my image stoped using translate animation..where i did mistake any one suggest me thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView i1;
    TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight1;
    Animation logoMoveAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        i1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        final Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate1);
        i1.startAnimation(myRotation);

        moveLefttoRight1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 200);
        moveLefttoRight1.setDuration(2000);
        moveLefttoRight1.setFillAfter(true);

        myRotation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                i1.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        logoMoveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sacle); 



        moveLefttoRight1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                i1.startAnimation(logoMoveAnimation);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

scale.xml:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:toXScale="2.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="2.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:duration="3000"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

u may try 
after translation has finished
img.setTranslation(value);
value = the position where image should be after translation

Comment: setTranslationX() or setTranslationY()